# Remove dictionary if we have value is nan/None/NaN/null for key using python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I want to remove dictionary if value is nan/None/NaN/null for key . If nan is the only value in case of phone_type work then remove full dictionary itself.

**Input Data**

```
dic = ['Customer_Number': 12345,'Phone_Number': [{'Phone_Type': 'Mobile', 'Phone': [1217]}, {'Phone_Type': 'work', 'Phone': [nan]}]]
```

**Expected Output Data**

```
dic = ['Customer_Number': 12345,'Phone_Number': [{'Phone_Type': 'Mobile', 'Phone': [1217]}]]
```

**code tried**

```
#define which elements you want to remove:
to_be_deleted = [[], {}, "", None, "nan",nan, "NaN", NaN]


def remove_empty_elements(jsonData):
    if isinstance(jsonData, list):
        print("jsonDAta:", jsonData)
        jsonData = [remove_empty_elements(elem) for elem in jsonData
                    if remove_empty_elements(elem) not in to_be_deleted]

    elif isinstance(jsonData, dict):
        jsonData = {key: remove_empty_elements(value) for key, value in jsonData.items()
                    if remove_empty_elements(value) not in to_be_deleted}


        if len(jsonData) == 1:
            return None

    return jsonData

res = remove_empty_elements(dic)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example solution:

```
to_delete = [ None, [None], "", None, "nan", "NaN"]

dic = {'Customer_Number': 12345,'Phone_Number': [{'Phone_Type': 'Mobile', 'Phone': [1217]}, {'Phone_Type': 'work', 'Phone': [None]}]}

for key in dic.keys():
    if isinstance(dic[key], list):
        for item in dic[key]:
            if isinstance(item, dict):
                item_keys =  list(item.keys())
                for key_2 in item_keys:
                    if item[key_2] in to_delete:
                        del item[key_2]
```

output

```
{'Customer_Number': 12345, 'Phone_Number': [{'Phone_Type': 'Mobile', 'Phone': [1217]}, {'Phone_Type': 'work'}]}
```

Change accordingly in order to catch more cases. This one only works if you have a list of dictionaries as value for the top level keys

Comment: dic is the list of dictionaires.

Comment: @NaveenGupta `dic = ['Customer_Number': 12345,'Phone_Number': [{'Phone_Type': 'Mobile', 'Phone': [1217]}]]` u cannot have this

Comment: It is not entering into last if statement. if item[key_2] in to_delete:

Comment: did you run the above example?

Comment: yes I ran the above code. It is not entering into that if condition

Comment: It is working fine in `Python 3.7.10`